# AmazonAWSHealthClient.DescribeEventsRequest: No such host is known

Tags: c#, health-monitoring, aws-sdk-net

I want to make a request for the health events on my AWS account. I use this code to do the request:

```
using (var client = new AmazonAWSHealthClient("accesskey", "privatekey", RegionEndpoint.EUCentral1))
{
    var request = new DescribeEventsRequest();

    var response = client.DescribeEventsAsync(request).Result;
}
```

But the response is "No such host is known". What do I need to change? Do I need to alter some settings on my AWS account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to switch out the **EUCentral1** in the clients constructor for **USEast1** and it worked (I was then missing some permissions, but that I can fix). Not providing a region for the client also didn't help, I specifically had to provide the USEast1 region. Apparently that region is the one that AWS treats as "Global", as you see "Global" selected as a region, when you are in the Personal Health Dashboard.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was getting the same error. Adding the region is what resolved it for me.